# Can I use TLS with Send-MailMessage cmdlet?

Tags: powershell

I am trying to send an email using PowerShell, but need to use TLS. Any way I can do that using Send-MailMessage cmdlet?

This is my code:

```
$file = "c:\Mail-content.txt"

if (test-path $file)
{

    $from = "afgarciact@gmail.com"
    $to = "<slopez@comfama.com.co>","<carloscu@comfama.com.co>"
    $pc = get-content env:computername
    $subject = "Test message " + $pc
    $smtpserver ="172.16.201.55"
    $body = Get-Content $file | Out-String


[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::ServerCertificateValidationCallback = { return $true }

     foreach ($recipient in $to)
    {
        write-host "Sent to $to"
        Send-MailMessage -smtpServer $smtpserver -from $from -to $recipient -subject $subject  -bodyAsHtml $body -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
    }



}
else
{
write-host "Configuración"
}
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Make sure your specify the `-UseSsl` switch:

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpserver -UseSsl -From $from -To $recipient -Subject $subject -BodyAsHtml $body -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

If the SMTP server uses a specific port for SMTP over TLS, use the `-Port` parameter:

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer $smtpserver -Port 465 -UseSsl -From $from -To $recipient -Subject $subject -BodyAsHtml $body -Encoding ([System.Text.Encoding]::UTF8)
```

If you want to make sure that TLS is always negotiated (and not SSL 3.0), set the `SecurityProtocol` property on the `ServicePointManager` class:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls,TLS11,TLS12'
```

Comment: But it says SSL. Does it use TLS instead?

Comment: It negotiates whatever the server offers, by default the highest of TLS 1.0 or SSL 3.0

Comment: I see. So, if Office 365, that would use TLS 1.2, right?

Comment: @Checho No, only SSL3 or TLS 1.0 by default (although O365 doesn't support SSL 3.0 anymore afaik). If O365 only offers TLS 1.1 and 1.2 you'll have to set the `SecurityProtocol` property, updated the answer

Comment: I tried that, but got this error: Exception setting "SecurityProtocol": "Cannot convert value "Tls12" to type "System.Net.SecurityProtocolType" due to invalid enumeration values. Specify one of the following enumerat
ion values and try again. The possible enumeration values are "Ssl3, Tls"."

Comment: Which version of powershell and Windows are you on?

Comment: Server 2008 R2; PowerShell 2.0. What version do I need?

Answer (score 1):

I have been fighting this all day. The fix for me ended up being needing to run this in a separate line first, and then I was able to run my `Send-MailMessage` commands:

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls,TLS11,TLS12'
```

Thank you for the suggestion!