# Powershell Send-MailMessage gives Mailbox unavailable. Error 5.7.60 on windows server 2016

Tags: powershell, smtp, powershell-5.0

I am trying to send an email from powershell on windows server 2016 with the code below but get an error.

```
Send-MailMessage -From 'datacompare@domainname.com' `
-To 'qm@domainname.com`
-Subject 'Test mail' -SmtpServer smtp5.domain.com `
-Body 'this is a test'
```

> Mailbox unavailable. The server response was: 5.7.60 SMTP; Client does not have permissions to send as this sender
> At line:1 char:1

1 -Before I even executed the code on the server I run it on my PC with no issues.

2 - I run it on a different windows server 2016 environment and I had no issue either.

3 - I thought the issue might be TLS/SSL, so i compared protocols between the two windows server 2016 environment and both use SSL 2.0.

3 - As per [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39967359/can-i-use-tls-with-send-mailmessage-cmdlet), I run below on the first line of my code and it still gave me an error.

```
[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = 'Tls,TLS11,TLS12'
```

4 - all the troubleshooting guides online has got me no where either.

Comment: SSL, TLS 1.0, and TLS 1.1 are obsolete and should not be used.  Only use TLS 1.2 or 1.3. 
 There is no such animal as SSL 2.0.  A Windows Server 2016 may not support the latest encryption modes in TLS 1.3.  You need to find out if you are inside a firewall and use port 25 (non secure) or require port 587 (secure).  You error is the same as this posting : https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/smtp-relay-error-550-5760-client-does-not-have/7ed99dad-e4c9-4ae9-86dc-e7505d233e6a

Comment: This is on-premises mail exchange server (if that makes any difference). I have put the `-port 25 and 587` flag on the script, enabled firewall on the server but still getting the same error. 
SMTP server has port 24 open.

Comment: This is just useful info to help debug.  Corporate Network block SMTP port number at firewall and use port forwarding to forward all SMTP to the corporate email proxy server to verify credentials.  So you cannot use SMTP to go the an outside email server like gmail.  SMTP also requires the FROM address and the credentials use the same account.  You also have to set the default credentials = true and do not include a username and password in the connection.  You have not provided enough code for me to determine if any of these conditions are reason for failure.

Comment: Thanks for the info.
this email is being sent internally. I will try the default credentials flag now but I should have seen this error when I run the same code on another windows server 2016 environment. 
I even tried `Get-Credentials` and put in my credentials and it still made no difference.
There is something with this server 2016 environment that is different

Comment: Did you also tru adding switch `-UseSsl` ?

Comment: yep, did that too and I got >Server does not support secure connection 

Comment: When you first log onto a Windows server account if is created on machine.  The also occurs when you first use Outlook on machine an email account is setup which establishes the default credentials. It is possible you never ran email manually on machine so SMTP does not have the default credentials.  Try running outlook on machine and then try SMTP again.

Comment: None of our servers have outlook and the other windows server 2016s that I can run this script on don't have outlook or has been run on them either. I found out today that a VBS code written many many years ago that also sends an e-mail works on this server but powershell send e-mail doesn't 

Comment: We need to see the VBS script.  SMTP has lots of configuration settings.  Powershell email should work if you use the same settings as the VBS script.  Does the VBS script still work?

Answer (score 0):

Check the SMTP protocol log on the SMTP server you're using. Is the connection authenticated or anonymous?

Check the mailbox that uses the 'datacompare@domainname.com' address. Does it accept mail from anonymous connections? Does it accept connections from only some senders?

If the connection is authenticated, is the account used in your script assigned the "Send As" right on the recipient's mailbox?

Comment: I don't have access to the server, but oddly enough, I left the script to run at start-up and restarted the server, and lo and behold, the email came through.
This addresses one of the issues but not when I want the email to be sent on a schedule.